# Drop down list using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i am using Google charts in website and data is entered from the Form. it is working fine now i want to change the Form field of Device by drop down menu from mysql database. i have written the code but it is not displaying the values in drop down list.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<tr><td>From Date:</td><td> <input name="from" type="text" id="from"></td></tr>

<tr><td>To Date:</td><td><input name="to" type="text" id="to"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Device:</td><td> <select name="Device" id="Device"><?php

$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$data = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Device FROM table")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
 $row['c'] = htmlentities($row['c']);
 echo '<option value="'.$row[c].'">'.$row[c].'</option>';
   }

  ?></select></td></tr>
  <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
  </form>
```

and i am getting this data in another php code like this

```
if(isset($_POST['from'])){ $from = $_POST['from'];  
if(isset($_POST['to'])){ $to = $_POST['to']; 
if(isset($_POST['Device'])){ $Device = $_POST['Device'];
```

i don't know what is the problem. if any one knows where i am wrong please tell me. Thanks

Comment: What is c? I think you mean $row['Device'].

Comment: Please run `SELECT DISTINCT Device FROM table` in your Database client. Check this query is correct.

Comment: yes i have checked it is correct and it shows the devices

Comment: If the above is correct please run print_r($row) in your while loop and look on the site for the result;

Comment: print_r($row) shows nothing. my drop down list is still empty

Comment: The below answer should do the job. print_r should display the array which i thought would show you the key was probably incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Device FROM table")
                               --------^
```

in your above code you are getting column **Device** not c.
so correct your code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
 $row['Device'] = htmlentities($row['Device']);
 echo '<option value="'.$row['Device'].'">'.$row['Device'].'</option>';
   }
```

*i think `mysqli_fetch_array()` will be more appropriate.

****Dont use MYSQL_* *** as they are depracted.

Comment: can you tell me one more thing? every thing is working fine when i click the submit button it shows the chart and my form display again now i want one more thing that when i click the submit button all the values in form displayed when the chart is displayed. i mean form will not be empty. how can i do this?

Comment: @Sandy you can achieve that by echoing the respective values of the form elements in there value attribute.like this               <tr><td>To Date:</td><td><input name="to" type="text" value="<?php echo $todate?>" id="to"></td></tr>

Comment: thanks @Rishabh Raj. it's working but first time it shows the notice in text box that undefined variable $to

Comment: @Sandy change "<?php echo $todate?>" to "<?php if isset($todate) echo $todate?>" .i hope this will do :)

Comment: i have change it to this <?php if(isset($_POST['from'])) echo $from?> now it is working perfectly. Thank you so much @Rishabh Raj for your help

Comment: @Sandy glad i could help :) enjoy coding

Comment: one last question :). how can i do this thing for Device?

Comment: @Sandy same approach will be applied for Device also

Comment: Value option is not appearing for Device. <select name="Device" id="Device">

Comment: @Sandy i think you want to display the selected option of the list.right?

Comment: Yes exactly @Rishabh Raj

Comment: @Sandy for that to happen u need to compare the option value with the database value and if they match write echo"selected".                     echo '<option value="'.$row['Device'];.'" if $device =$row['Device'] echo "selected">'.$row['Device'].'</option>';

Answer (score 0):

please check your mysql connection and die() script just terminate the script if it is false, if your database or sql query has error your code will terminate form die() function.